# xerces c++ XML parser uses wchar_t for XMLCh on windows, but uses uint16_t on linux. This causes problems with porting my application

Tags: c++, xml, linux, xerces-c

I've developed a C++ application using windows and Cygwin, and would like to get it working on my Linux system. I'm using the Xerces xml parser library, and am having issues compiling due to differences in the usage of the XMLCh type. On windows it is mapped to wchar_t, but on Linux it is mapped to uint16_t. I see in the release notes that it says "If the option /Zc:wchar_t is specified, map XMLCh to wchar_t." This sounds like what I want to do, but I'm unsure how to do this. Am I to recompile the xerces source with this option, or is it a compile option to use for my application. It doesn't seem to work when I use it for my own application, and I can't find any resources online to help me. Is this option what it sounds like it is, and if so, what are the steps to making it work? Thanks!

Comment: "/Zc:wchar_t" is a Visual Studio option.  You won't find it on other systems. 
 The whole point of using something like `XMLCh` is that it can be different on different systems.  What problem are you actually having with it?

Comment: The code that I've written use XMLCh as wchar_t, and I don't want to change my implementation. I'm getting compile errors because of this.

Comment: Well `XMLCh` isn't `wchar_t`.  `XMLCh` is a 2-byte type intended for UTF-16 encoded strings.  The size of `wchar_t` is undefined (it's most likely 4 bytes on your system), and it isn't necessarily appropriate for UTF-16.

Comment: I should clarify; the implementation of xerces on Windows uses XMLCh typedefed to wchar_t. I have written my code to conform to this standard, and am now getting compile errors because of the difference in implementation. Is there a simple way to make my code work without having to make extensive changes, or will I have to have different implementations of my application on each system?

Comment: Use `XMLCh` everywhere and don't assume it's a `wchar_t`.  If you need to pass an `XMLCh` string to some other part of your code, convert it to the appropriate encoding.  On Linux, `wchar_t` is usually a 4-byte type appropriate for UTF-32.  In C++ you have to think about encodings when dealing with text.